# Twisted making a function non-blocking

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I am using twisted for making an `async` webserver (to learn the idea behind even based asynchronous programming). consider this scenario , server when gets a `GET` request on some endpoint, ex `http:localhost:8000/api/v1/calc_fact?num=1000` calculates the factorial of 1000 and return back the result. this part is easy to get. I am also aware of deferred API. how can i define my function `calc_factorial()` so that it return a deferred and the overall result is non-blocking.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Use `deferToThread` as shown in http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/threading.html

Comment: @KlausD. is that the only way? say insted of using this function my function makes a call to db in that case also this is the correct way?

Comment: No, there are several ways. For a DB call twisted has database module that is async.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for the reply. i hope i got it

Comment: @KlausD. also threads are not sclable . that was the whole point of using `twisted` . as far as i understand defetToThread just hands the method to a thread and handle callbacks and errorbacks in a thread safe manner. but again whats the use of using twisted then?

Comment: Asynchronous processing does not mean automatic scaling. Scaling has to be handled in addition. You will be bound to the Python GIL even in Twisted as long as you don't run multiple processes. The advange of Twisted is a non-blocking process that will be responsive.

Comment: @KlausD. i didnt mean utomatic scaling what i meant was `a little better performance` than original threaded way. i will try to say what i mean. lets start from scratch we have a web server that say by default can handle `50 requests/sec` now we have multiple clients so we used threding and launched a new thread for an incoming reuwst so now we have a sever which can handle say a little more (100 req/sec) but we cant go on increasing thread so next choice is to  use `thread pools` .to avoid all this hustle and a new way was to use event-driven model(twisted) but again using threads in twisted?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar.

In your resource you need to return a server.NOT_DONE_YET and add the calc_factorial deferred callback like this

```
def render_GET(self, request):
    d = Deferred()
    reactor.callLater(1, d.callback, None)
    d.addCallback(self.calc_factorial, request)
    d.addErrback(rror_handler, request)
    return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

Then inside the calc_factorial you write into the request:

```
def calc_factorial(self, request):
    # something something
    request.write("factorial calc done")
    request.finish()
```

Once you write request finish it will trigger the NOT_DONE_YET

Comment: i think this is a hack right? because we are creating a `Deferred` object and then attaching a callback to it whit the original function which was meant to RETURN `deferred`. this will work obviously but the correct way should be using `deferToThread` . callback is something which is supposed to run after the original `TIME_CONSUMING_FUNCTION` has been processed.

Comment: mm dont know what do you mean by hack, you can see this same structure in the doc with _delayedRender and NOT_DONE_YET http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/web/howto/web-in-60/asynchronous-deferred.html